# Find the radix of $32+3=35$

Tags: linear-algebra

I know this is pretty simple one but I messed up. Can anyone give me the solution for $32+3=35$. the question is to find the base.
I tried to do this:
Suppose base is $b$

$$3\times b^1+2\times b^0+3\times b^0=3\times b^1+5\times b^0$$

$$3b+2+3=3b+5$$
$$3b-3b=5-5$$

Comment: Hem, what about decimal ?

Comment: This is true in every base for which the digits $2$, $3$ and $5$ are defined as $1+1$, $1+1+1$ and $1+1+1+1+1$ respectively (i.e., every natural base larger than $5$).

Answer (score 1):

The reason you can't get a solution for $b$ is that every base $b$ in which those digits exist (any base $b > 5$) is a base in which that equation is true.

Comment: Ok so the answer is base>5?

Comment: @S.tya Looks like it!

Answer (score 1):

As long as radix b is larger than 5 (so that "35" makes sense), 32+ 3= 35 in **any** such radix!